# (nav) click instead of hover, jquery old/new version

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#nav ul").css({display: "none"});
$("#nav li").toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vw;
}

#nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  float: left;
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.2vw;
}

#nav ul {
  width: 130%;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("images/bg01.png");
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

#nav ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}


#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html" id="was">home</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">news</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">lol1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">lol2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">news2</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">lol</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">comments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using a jquery for my nav(click instead of hover). Working with 1.6.2

version but not with 2.2.2. I don't know how to make it work on jquery version

2.2.2? If something missing tell me

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/r93f3wyf/
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/  See dupe for better alternative

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you have:

```
#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

If you don't want to show it on hover - remove this.

Comment: not working, anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because `.toggle()` event is depracted in jquery version 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You can rather toggle some class to element and then do toggling decision for event:

```
$("#nav li").click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('dotoggle'))
   $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
 else
   $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
 $(this).toggleClass('dotoggle')
});
```